# Failed to import dataclasses module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

Today I installed python 3.7 from apt-get to try out the new dataclasses module. I installed it seperately because python3.6 wasn't upgradeable to 3.7.

When I type: `python3.7 --version`, it gives me: `>>> Python 3.7.0a2` as my current version.

The problem is that I can't seem to import dataclasses.

my import statement is: `from dataclasses import dataclass` as instructed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

This is the error message it's giving me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataclasses'
```

I even tried installing the dataclasses module with pip3: `pip3 install dataclasses`. Not sure if that's necessary though.

Any suggestion on what might be the problem?

[EDIT] Just tried it with a python3.6 console and it worked fine .. weird.

Comment: The pip package `dataclasses` is a backport for Python 3.6. Maybe this explains why it worked fine when you tried with Python 3.6

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @wim `python3.7 -m venv venv_dir`

This command will:

1. Use python3.7 to run the command
2. The `-m` flag tells the interpreter to run the next argument as a script
3. `venv` is a module, and because of the `-m` flag it will be run as a script
4. Finally, the `venv_dir` is given to the `venv` module as an argument which
   this module will use to create a virtual environment directory at

Once this command is run now you'll have a nice sandbox for messing around/testing the dataclasses module.

- To activate this virtual environment be sure to run `source venv_dir/bin/activate` before you begin. This command will run the script at `venv_dir/bin/activate` to set up the necessary environment variables and other things for you
- To deactivate, simply run `deactivate` after activating

Comment: Better:  `python3.7 -m venv venv_dir`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.